# How to access initial state array of object from reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm facing a problem accessing initialstates array of object for redux.

I have this initial states:

```
 export const initialState = [
  {
    blogPosts: [
      {
        title: "",
        category: "",
        logo: "",
        author: "",
        date: "",
        timeToRead: "",
        blogImage: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  { filterStatus: "" },
  { filterBy: "" },
];
```

and I only want to change the `filterStatus` from my `reducer`. But trying to do so its changing and also adding one more object in the array.

I was trying this code from my reducer:

```
case SEARCH_AUTHOR:
      return [
        ...state,   
        (state[1].filterStatus = "author"),

      ];
```

How can I change get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
case SEARCH_AUTHOR:
  return [
    ...state,   
    (state[1].filterStatus = "author"),
];
```

Is creating a new object with the entirety of `state` - (`...state`)
And then modifying the 2nd item's filter status, but only returning the result of the expression which is the newly set value `"author"`.

There are many ways to implement what you wanted, I think the simplest would be to copy the array then modify the copy before returning.

```
case SEARCH_AUTHOR:
  const copy = [...state]
  copy[1] = {...copy[1], filterStatus: 'author'}
  return copy;
```

What this does is:

1. Create a shallow copy of the array - this copies the **same object references** to a new array
2. Overwrite item at index `1` with a **new object** that spreads (copies) the original and then overwrites the required key

Another possible solution would be to use `map` or `reduce` on the array and returning the modified new array, or `splice` a new object at the correct index

Answer (score 1):

You can use splice `state.splice(1, 1, { filterStatus: "author" }` to remove the `{ filterStatus: "" }` and set instead `{ filterStatus: "author" }` and return a copy of the state by `return [...state]`.

```js
const initialState = [
    {
      blogPosts: [
        {
          title: "",
          category: "",
          logo: "",
          author: "",
          date: "",
          timeToRead: "",
          blogImage: "",
        },
      ],
    },
    { filterStatus: "" },
    { filterBy: "" },
  ];
  
  const changeFilter = () => {
    initialState.splice(1, 1, { filterStatus: "author" } )
    return [ ...initialState ];
  }
  
  console.log(changeFilter())
```

Answer (score -2):

Use **var** instead of **const**

```
 export var initialState = [
 {
  blogPosts: [
    {
    title: "",
    category: "",
    logo: "",
    author: "",
    date: "",
    timeToRead: "",
    blogImage: "",
    },
    ],
  },
    { filterStatus: "" },
    { filterBy: "" },
 ];
```